# Select a value in a specific optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select with multiple optgroups

For example

```
<select id="Numbers">
     <option value="0">Select One</option>
     <optgroup label="A" id="A">
          <option value="123">123</option>
          <option value="456">456</option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup label="B" id="B">
          <option value="123">123</option>
          <option value="456">456</option>
     </optgroup>
</select>
```

Since the values in both optgroups are the same, is there a way to select an option depending on its optgroup?

So I want to select the option with the value of "123" in optgroup with the id of "B"

Comment: Other than something like `$('#Numbers optgroup#B option[value=123]')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have provided id `B`. You can use [**ID selector**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and [**Attribute Value Selector**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

You can use

```
 $('#B option[value="123"]').prop('selected', true)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KB4RY/)

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery you can limit the selection to the children of the `optgroup` you want.  In this case:

```
$("optgroup#B > option[value='123']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

SORRY, THOUGHT THEY WERE CHECKBOXES. THIS WILL NOT WORK.

Do you mean automatically show it as checked, on loading the page? If so use jQuery:
`$("#B").children('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);`